# Why aren't fixed retainers (metal wires) behind front row of teeth affected by the MRI's? Isn't it magnetic?

Tags: mri, procedural-expectations, retainers

I've had plenty of MRI's in my life, and I know the drill: take off the glasses, bra with a metal clasp, hair-tie with a metal band, all metal jewelry, etc. It makes sense. You don't want to put someone adorned in metal inside a magnetic machine.

But what I've never understood is how come it's okay that my fixed-retainer (metal wire behind the front rows of my teeth --- after braces) is permissible in the MRI? I mean, yeah, I can't remove it... so there's that... But I'm not talking about proper etiquette and all that jazz -- I want to know the science behind it.

***Why have I never once felt any magnetic pull or anything on the metal wires behind my teeth while I'm having my MRI's?***

Would the other metal items I remove (listed above) likely not have an impact either?? It's just because it ruins the imaging? Is that's what going on there?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3722691/